# Is there any way to detect user clicks in the javascript popup?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-chrome

I want to check whether the user liked the facebook page opened in the popup. I know that we can't detect the user activity in the javascript popup due to the [Same origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). 
I want to find whether the user clicked the like button in the opened facebook page in the javascript popup.

If it is not possible, then how the social exchange sites like `http://addmefast.com` , `http://like4like.org` etc., are working.

**UPDATE :**

If I want to do it in the same domain, I can do it with the following snippet

```
var myWindow = window.open("abc.html","MsgWindow", "width=500","height=600");
$(myWindow).on('click', 'a', function() {alert('a')});
```

But, I want to do it another website. So, Following snippet can't work :(

```
var myWindow = window.open("http://google.com","MsgWindow", "width=500","height=600");
$(myWindow).on('click', 'a', function() {alert('a')});
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What have you tried so far? Do you own both sites? and what do you mean by a "javascript popup"?

Comment: I have updated the question. I own only one site. The site opening in the popup is not my site. So, I can't edit any javascript in the opened popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The truth is that you can't. You need to own both sides, or speak with the other party to set up a policy; use the same domain; or have the user use an older/less secure browser.

You could however get the 'likes' from someone by using Facebook's API, given the privacy options from the user of course.

The sites you mentioned, and other sites that collect user data (annoying IMO) do so by having the owner of the website implement part of their code (like [i.po.st](http://www.po.st/) does on [Explosm.net](http://explosm.net)). They offer a solution such as adding "Sharing" options, meanwhile they collect user data.
It's not very different to what **Google** does with [Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/).

Another way they use is by adding advertisement, not only they profit from advertising, but they also collect user data. So let's suppose **Company A** pays thousands of websites to show advertisements (like [Google Ads](http://www.google.com/intl/en/ads/)).
This website would be able to get information from a LOT of users from a LOT of websites, by showing their ads, and adding tracking code *(shameless evil creatures)*. They either use it to show more interesting advertisement, sell it, or share it with other similar sites, and form a network of *evil doers* who invade your privacy for "targeted advertising".

Comment: Then, How social exchange sites like addmefast and like4like are fetching the information without using facebook api?. I can't find how they are doing.